# Losing connection to mongoDB when running too many tests

Tags: java, mongodb, junit

I have a problem with MongoDb when running too many JUnit tests which use my local test database.
When I'm running all tests one-by-one, everything is ok and every test pass.
But when I'm trying to "Run all tests", somewhere after the 80th test I'm losing the connection to Mongo and all next tests fail.
It is strange because as I understand and see "run all tests" just makes all tests running successively.

I drop my db in @After of the every test so i thought that maybe the creating of the own, unique database for every test may solve the problem(before i used single one). But it didn't. I'm still losing the connection after some 80+ test(different every time).

Maybe driver doesn't have enough time to get response from Mongo at the some moment and it leads to the fail?

I use 2.11.3 Mongo Java driver.
Need help.
Thank you.

Here is the error stack:

```
Sep 13, 2013 5:32:07 PM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection
WARNING: Exception executing isMaster command on /127.0.0.1:27017
java.io.EOFException
     at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:48)
     at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)
     at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
     at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)
     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:142)
     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:106)
     at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:162)
     at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:170)
     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:547)
     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:334)
     at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:618)
     at com.mongodb.DB.wrapCommand(DB.java:282)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:260)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:244)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:301)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:199)
     at com.mongodb.DB.dropDatabase(DB.java:557)
     at com.*******.dbconnection.mongodb.BaseMongodbTest.tearDown(BaseMongodbTest.java:102)
     at com.*******.rpcserver.methods.BaseTestClient.tearDown(BaseTestClient.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
     at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)




com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /127.0.0.1:27017 failed on database test_mydb_fb19fd07-6e4f-4
     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:253)
     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
     at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:262)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:244)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:301)
     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:199)
     at com.mongodb.DB.dropDatabase(DB.java:557)
     at com.*******.dbconnection.mongodb.BaseMongodbTest.tearDown(BaseMongodbTest.java:102)
     at com.*******.rpcserver.methods.BaseTestClient.tearDown(BaseTestClient.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
     at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
     at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:48)
     at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)
     at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
     at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)
     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:142)
     at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
     ... 42 more
```

Comment: Are you loosing or losing connection?

Comment: @interlude, sorry :)
Losing, of course.
ty for the correction.

Comment: Can you post the log covering the failure period from the MongoDB server?  Is it standalone? Sharded? Replica set? The exception looks like the server severed the connection abruptly (e.g., the server crashed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I found out where the problem was.
There was a silly mistake in our test client: new Mongo object was created for every test case!
The command

> db.serverStatus().connections

shows us that the number of available connections is about 200 but every new Mongo instance creates new 10(by default) connections. So i simply exceeded that limit as it was shown in logs(you can read them, for ex., by executing **mongo --eval="printjson(db.adminCommand({getLog:'global'}))"**)

The solution is to create factory class, which keeps single instance of Mongo object which is used in every test case (I also initialize DB and MongoClient Instances here and recommend you to do the same if you need them too).

I highly recommend to read this topic, it solves a similar problem(and helped me a lot!):
[Mongo opens too many connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891011/mongo-opens-too-many-connections)

Thanks to @RobMoore and @interlude for prompt replies and willingness to help!